# Swipe from right to left in launcher

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, right-to-left, left-to-right

I'm make custom launcher, but I don't know what is this view in image.
It's work like viewpager but I think it isn't viewpager. I swipe from right to left it show.
What is this view ?, How can i do like this ? Thank you

[image: Home screen swipe right to lefte]

Comment: maybe it help: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Comment: It's not bad solution , It will start new activity.  But in refer app I can keep swipe like viewpager